# Why is python giving me a fatal error upon downloading a package?

Tags: python

When trying to install Marine-traffic-api im getting an error:

```
Installing collected packages: ujson, Marine-Traffic-API
  Running setup.py install for ujson: started
    Running setup.py install for ujson: finished with status 'error'
    Complete output from command /home/benjamin/PycharmProjects/ShipTracking/venv/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pycharm-packaging/ujson/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-record-ys30b_z8/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /home/benjamin/PycharmProjects/ShipTracking/venv/include/site/python3.7/ujson:
    Warning: 'classifiers' should be a list, got type 'filter'
    running install
    running build
    running build_ext
    building 'ujson' extension
    creating build
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/python
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/lib
    x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC -I./python -I./lib -I/home/benjamin/PycharmProjects/ShipTracking/venv/include -I/usr/include/python3.7m -c ./python/ujson.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/./python/ujson.o -D_GNU_SOURCE
    In file included from ./python/ujson.c:39:0:
    ./python/py_defines.h:39:10: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory
     #include <Python.h>
              ^~~~~~~~~~
    compilation terminated.
    error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Install the needed packages:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential python3 python-dev python3-dev
```

After that, run:

```
pip install --no-cache-dir ujson
```